# Can Stack Overflow be cloned for internal use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, so-enterprise

ISTM that a Stack Overflow-based setup would work great in many work environments. There are questions that can be answered internally, but you don't know who it is that may have the answer. Questions specific to a certain company or department, that wouldn't fit on Stack Overflow, or in cases where it's hard to be specific about your code when asking questions on Stack Overflow because thereby you might divulge too much of your company's secrets and possibly future directions/projects, etc.

I guess what I'm really asking is if there is such a thing as a "Stack Overflow in a box" or an Open Source Stack Overflow-esque framework that can be deployed for an internal work group? If not, what is the closest thing to it?