# Why doesn't Stack Overflow make private spaces available?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I asked a question here: [Can Stack Overflow be cloned for internal use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185339/can-stack-overflow-be-cloned-for-internal-use) which is obviously on people's minds, because it was closed as a duplicate of this: [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

So why doesn't Stack Overflow make a private version available - same exact functionality as the public Stack Overflow, but only available to authorized users? Obviously they could charge a fee for this, but I would think this could be a win-win situation for SO and businesses who want the SO functionality but want to keep the questions and answers "in house."

Comment: Note that there is still an enterprise version available for intranet use, although details are not publicly available. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available

Answer (score 13):

[**Stack Overflow Enterprise is available**](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal private use, but that is intended for larger organizations only.

Stack Overflow once tried a subscription service for the public, but it didn't work.

## [Changes to Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)

> ### Charging for Stack Exchange hasn’t exactly worked
>
> Our first idea was Stack Exchange… call it Stack Exchange 1.0. We thought we’d make our software available on a SaaS basis, a.k.a. “white label Stack Overflow,” so that anyone could start a site on a new topic in exchange for money.
>
> When we launched Stack Exchange, we imagined thousands of sites would start to sprout up on every possible topic. Harley Davidson belt buckles, mathematics, unicorns, you name it.
>
> However, by setting a price ($129-$5000/month, depending on traffic) to cover the cost of servers and bandwidth, we discouraged a lot of people from making sites that might have been great. And by allowing anyone with a credit card to make a site, we got a lot of ghost-town sites that nobody visited. We also got a lot of duplication: multiple sites on the same topic, competing for the same people and preventing one other from hitting critical mass.
>
> Bottom line, it just wasn’t working. We’ve been in beta for half a year now, and we only have a handful of sites that get enough traffic to provide quality, timely answers to difficult questions.